# iOS Silent Notifications with distribution certs and provisionings issue

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, push, silent

I have a problem with my application regarding to Silent Notifications:

When I run my app from Xcode (**using DEV** certificates and provisionings), **remote notifications are working** (the normal ones with alert, and de the silent notifications.

But when I upload my app to Testflight (**using DIST** certificates and provisioning), **Remote notifications with Alert are working, but the Silent notifications are not working**.

Does anyone knows why this could happen? how can I solve this?

(currently using Xcode 7.3.1, iPhone 6S - iOS 9.3.2, iPhone 5S - iOS 9.3.2, iPad mini - iOS 9.3.2)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Silent pushes do not necessarily get delivered immediately, but you will not notice this when using Xcode/dev certificates. Plug in your iPhone to a power supply, make sure the phone is not sleeping and your app is running (foreground or background) and try again.

Comment: I plugged-in my devices in to my Mac and checked in  Xcode Window/Devices what are my NSLogs printing, and only the Normal Notifications (with alert) are printing, but the Silent ones never prints, so never arrives to my device.  (this is when I test my app downloaded from testflight, because when I test running my app from Xcode, everything is working fine)

Comment: Is the app running in the background or terminated?

Comment: I've tried with the app running in the bg and when is active too.

For the 3 application states:  active, inactive, and running in background, I've tried with Dev certs and it works like a charm (normal and silent)

Comment: but the problem is when I use Dist certs.  Could be the library used in the server side??  (but I don't think so, I use node-apn)